# A signature in KNNClassifier.class refers to term shared

Tags: scala, apache-spark, knn

I have used KNN mlib scala spark :
https://github.com/saurfang/spark-knn/tree/master/project

and i have this error :

```
Error:(28, 19) bad symbolic reference.
A signature in KNNClassifier.class refers to term shared
in package org.apache.spark.ml.param which is not available.
It may be completely missing from the current classpath, or the version on
the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling KNNClassifier.class.
    val knn = new KNNClassifier()
```

help please !!!